# php email is coming in plain text instead of HTML

Tags: php, html-email

I have a form which submits an email and passes the form values into the email as well as an attachment. The email is submitting and the attachment is coming through just fine but it is coming in with plain text instead of HTML. You can actually see all the HTML tags in the email instead of rendering the HTML.

I've done quite a bit of searching and trial and error so far with no luck. Any ideas on what I did wrong here:

php:

```
<?php

// if there is post
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST) ) {

        // if thre is an attachment
            if(!empty($_FILES['attachment']['name'])) {

        // store some variables
        $file_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
        $temp_name = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];

        // get the extension of the file
        $base = basename($file_name);
        $extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));

// only allow these file types
$allowed_extensions = array(".doc", "docx", ".pdf", ".zip", ".csv", ".xls", "xlsx");

    // check that this file type is allowed
    if(in_array($extension,$allowed_extensions)) {

        // mail essentials
        $from = $_POST['email'];

        // multiple recipients
        $to  = 'email@email.com,'.$_POST['email'];



        // subject
        $today_day=date("d") ;
        $today_month=date("m") ;
        $today_year=date("Y") ;

        $subject = 'Professional Services Confirmation: '." Date and Time:       ".$_POST['ScheduledMonth']."/".$_POST['ScheduledDay']."/". $_POST['ScheduledYear'].' at '. $_POST['ScheduledHour'].":".$_POST['ScheduledMin']." ".$_POST['AMPM']." ".$_POST['TimeZone'];


// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Professional Services Confirmation</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#434344;
    line-height:140%;
}

h1 {
    font-size:23px;
    color:#434344;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:10px;
}

h2 {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#434344;
    font-weight:normal;
}

td {padding:5px 5px;}

.bg {background-color:#f1f1f1;}

.item {color:#666666; font-weight:bold;}
.content{
   height:auto; 
   width: 480px; 
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>
';
$message=$message.'
<table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="border:1px solid #434344;">
  <tr>
  <td style="border-bottom:2px solid #434344;">
  <img src="" />
  </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="680" height="382">';

$message=$message.'

<h1>Conference Call Confirmation</h1>';

$message=$message.'
<table width="680" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" valign="top"><h2>Client Information:</h2></td>
        </tr>


      <tr class="bg">
        <td valign="top" style="width:180px;"><p class="item">Name: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['name'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>  

                                <tr class="bg">
        <td valign="top" style="width:180px;"><p class="item">Company: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['company'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>      

      <tr class="bg">
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Phone #: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['phone'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>      

      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Email: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['email'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>      

      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Account #: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['account_num'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>

      <tr class="bg">
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Salesperson: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['salesperson'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>        
<tr>
<td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" valign="top"><h2>Conference Scheduling:</h2></td>
        </tr>


      <tr class="bg">
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Event Date: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message.$_POST['ScheduledMonth']."/".$_POST['ScheduledDay']."/".    $_POST['ScheduledYear'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>
      <tr >
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Event Time: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['ScheduledHour'].":".$_POST['ScheduledMin']." ".$_POST['AMPM'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>
      <tr class="bg">
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Timezone: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['TimeZone'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>


      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Duration of Call: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['duration'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>

      <tr class="bg">
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Lines Reserved: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['lines_reserved'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>

      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Project ID: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['project_id'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>

      <tr class="bg">
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Call Title / Topic: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['call_title_topic'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>                               

      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Moderators / Host Name(s): </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['moderators'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>       

      <tr class="bg">
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Speaker Name(s): </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['speakers'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>           

      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Fields to be collected <br /> from participants: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['collect_fields'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>                                       

      <tr class="bg">
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Seperate Host / Speaker <br /> dial-in # needed: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['seperate_dialin'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>                                       

      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Special Script Required: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['special_script'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>       

      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Script: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content">';
$message = $message. $_POST['script'];
$message = $message.'</td>
        </tr>   

      <tr class="bg">
        <td valign="top"><p class="item">Uploads: </p></td>
        <td valign="top"></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" class="content"><p>Please Note that all uploads are located on our Dropbox account under the folder named "Event_Items"</p></td>
        </tr>                                               


      ';

$message = $message.'         
      <tr> 
      <td colspan="4" valign="top"><span class="style5"></span></td>
      </tr>

      '; 
$message = $message.' 
    </table>    

    <br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


 <p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>

                ';


    // things you need
    $file = $temp_name;
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));     

    //standard mail headers
    $header = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";



    // declaring we have multiple parts of email (i.e plain text and attachment)
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";

    // message part
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";

    // file attachment part
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";



    //send the mail
    if (mail($to, $subject, "", $header)) {
    //redirect to the thank you page
    header('Location: http://www.somesite.com/thankyou.php');
        } else {
            echo "Fail";
            }

    } else {
        echo "file type not allowed";
}

 } else {
    echo "no file posted";
  }
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: I think you're also missing a second linebreak before the first MIME boundary: `$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";` should end in `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: Actually, looks like I'm not correct about the linebreak. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is breaking your headers:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
       ^
```

It contains an `s` (*pluralized*) => `$headers`, change it to `$header`.

all your other header variables are (*singular*) `$header`

---

Plus, if I may quote Michael in his comment

*"I think you're also missing a second linebreak before the first MIME boundary:

`$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";`

should end in `\r\n\r\n`"*

if you're still having problems. However, from Michael's additional comment, this may not be required. Thank you Michael for checking up on that.

Comment: Smacking myself right now... lol I must have looked over this code for a good half hour and didn't pick up on that smh. Thank you! much appreciated!

Comment: @NewB You're very much welcome. However, as Michael stated in a comment, try that if you're still having problems.

Comment: nope no more problems, the plural headers was the cause and everything is working perfectly now.

Comment: @NewB That's great, glad to hear it. Thanks for the update, *cheers*